# ie7 css; position relative problem?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Please have a look at the following url: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/johan/fysiosteo/

I want the image to be on the right side of the content, so i made the container position: relative and the image position: absolute. Works great, except in IE7. So I would like to know how to fix it. Is it an IE bug, or did I miss something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine in IE9...why don't you set the image as a background of the content block and position that background right (background-position property).

Comment: Good idea, that didnt cross my mind :) I'll accept your answer. But i would still like to know why ie7 messes it up though

Comment: Great! Probably IE7 is just messed up with the positioning  properties. Good luck!